# Access crashes when opening linked table via MySQL ODBC driver

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, odbc

1. We installed the 32 bit ODBC driver (8.0.27) for MySQL on a Windows 10 machine
2. Made a successfull connection via SSL to a MySQL 8 server
3. Initially tables most table can be opened, but Access crashes often when reopening tables (sometimes also on the first try)

We already removed JSON fields from the database as I read this might cause problems.
Also we it happens on fresh access database files which were not saved.

How can this be debugged?

EDIT: I found this error in the Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application:

```
Faulting application name: MSACCESS.EXE, version: 16.0.14701.20262, time stamp: 0x61ba8118
Faulting module name: myodbc8w.dll, version: 8.0.27.0, time stamp: 0x614d5c88
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000632f0
Faulting process id: 0x260c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7f7f26d5e7f87
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0\myodbc8w.dll
Report Id: 80eac648-9e55-41ff-8e53-2f8514383821
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

How can this be fixed?

It happens also on another machine.

EDIT: I found this error report:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105503

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug in the connector version 8.0.27 which will be fixed in 8.0.28

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105503

As 8.0.28 is not yet released, I downgraded to 8.0.26 which seems not to suffer from this crashes.